# Custom script from Asset Menu in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

As you know, you can create a script clicking the right mouse button and choosing "`Create/C# Script`".

It automatically generates a C# class derived from `Monobehaviour` and inserts `Start()` and `Update()` methods.

I need to create a similar Asset Menu option that will also generate a C# script but derived from another class.

How to do it?

Comment: Check out [this link](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/editor-scripting)

Comment: A script is JUST a file, so just search about creating a file in c#, wrote what u wish and save the file with the correct extension, I think that u will need to call an AssetDatabase.SaveAssets or some dirty check to make unity understand that u've added new file and to generate the .meta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understand correctly, you want to be able to create a custom C# script that inherits from a different class and not MonoBehaviour.

Here is an article about the topic:
https://support.unity.com/hc/en-us/articles/210223733-How-to-customize-Unity-script-templates

Comment: I also have this initial thought but I think that he wants to create a new file

Comment: From what he describes he wants a file like the default script that inherits from MonoBehaviour and has the default Start and Update methods, but instead of inheriting from MonoBehaviour he wants to automatically inherit from another class, which is what the article I attached explains